# ServiceController status does not correctly reflect the actual service status

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have this code running a powershell script if my service is starting or stopped.

```
Timer timer1 = new Timer();

ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService");

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer1.Interval = 10000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending) || (sc.Status ==  ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped))
        {
            StartPs();
        }
    }

    private void StartPs()
    {
        PSCommand cmd = new PSCommand();
        cmd.AddScript(@"C:\windows\security\dard\StSvc.ps1");
        PowerShell posh = PowerShell.Create();
        posh.Commands = cmd;
        posh.Invoke();
    }
```

It's working fine when I kill my service from cmd prompt
But even if my service is up and running, the powershell script continues to execute itself (it appends a file on the computer)
Any idea why ?

Comment: Would it be correct to say that powershell is orthogonal to this question, and the *real* question is: why does my `StartPending`/`Stopped` check not work correctly?

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoints to see what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `ServiceController.Status` property *is not always live*; it is lazily evaluated the first time it is requested, but (unless requested) **only** that time; subsequent queries to `Status` *will not* normally check the actual service. To force this, add:

```
sc.Refresh();
```

before your `.Status` check:

```
private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    sc.Refresh();
    if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending ||
        sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
    {
        StartPs();
    }
}
```

Without that `sc.Refresh()`, if it was `Stopped` (for example) initially, it will *always* say `Stopped`.

Comment: Ugh! Seriously, Microsoft? Why not build a refresh into the `Status` call itself (like I'll probably end up doing myself)?? Or at least have a `Status.Refresh` method to make it obvious.

Comment: Wow Man!! @Marc You made my day. It's not obvious to understand that we have to call sc.Refresh() to be sure about the latest status.